# Python paramiko chdir doesn't work. getcwd() returns None

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm using paramiko to connect to my FTP this way:

```python
transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

transport.connect(
                  username=user,
                  password=pwd,
                  )

client = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
client.chdir("/foo/bar/")
```

and i get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

And using `getcwd` returns `None`. I know the `dir` exists because if I do `client.listdir()` it actually returns the list of the files I want to download. Is it a bug ? Am i missing something ?

So here is the full details:

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file(cwd/"paramiko.log")

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(
                 username=user,
                 password=pwd,
                 )

client = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
print(client.listdir())
```

returns list of files:

```
['Dax30_Call 2020-06 (Jun 2020).csv','Dax30_Put 2018-06 (Jun 2018).csv','EuroStoxx50_Call 2018-11 (Nov 2018).csv','EuroStoxx50_Put 2022-12 (Dec 2022).csv','EuroStoxx50_Call 2019-06 (Jun 2019).csv','EuroStoxx50_Call 2020-06 (Jun 2020).csv','EuroStoxx50_Call 2022-12 (Dec 2022).csv']
```

I know the dir exists because the FTP is mine, and i can browse it when connecting to it via terminal. The files are in /foo/bar directory.

```
print(client.listdir("/foo/bar"))
```

or

```
print(client.chdir("/foo/bar"))
```

returns (no matters the order)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Data/Dev/OptionChain/download_data.py", line 91, in <module>
print(client.listdir("/foo/bar"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 186, in listdir
return [f.filename for f in self.listdir_attr(path)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 207, in listdir_attr
t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPENDIR, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 780, in _request
return self._read_response(num)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 832, in _read_response
self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 861, in _convert_status
raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

I see nothing of interest in the paramiko log file

Comment: `client.listdir()` or `client.listdir("/foo/bar/")`?

Comment: Try removing the trailing slash, ie `client.chdir("/foo/bar")`. It may be confusing paramiko.

Comment: `client.listdir()` returns the list i want to download. `client.listdir("foo/bar")` returns the error. Removing the trailing slash doesn't change anything

Comment: So `client.listdir()` after `client.chdir("/foo/bar/")` returns the files even if the `chdir` actually throws an exception? Can you show the code? Do catch and ignore the exception? - What if you call `client.listdir()` without even calling `client.chdir("/foo/bar/")`?

Comment: I've edited my question ;)

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. I do not get how calling `client.listdir()` proves that `/foo/bar` exists. What exactly does your call of `client.listdir()` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's something related with sftp user rights

```
$ ssh user1@xx.xx.xx.xxx -p22
$ cd /foo/bar
$ ls 
'Dax30_Call 2018-06 (Jun 2018).csv','Dax30_Put 2019-03 (Mar 2019).csv'

$ realpath 'Dax30_Call 2018-06 (Jun 2018).csv'
'/foo/bar/Dax30_Call 2018-06 (Jun 2018).csv'

$ sftp -v -P 22 user2@xx.xx.xx.xxx
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /bar
```

I'll go with that for now ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You list your root folder and there's no `foo` folder.

So we cannot see any reason why changing a folder to `/foo/bar` should work.

The fact that you can see the folder, when you *"browse it when connecting to it via terminal"* is irrelevant here. Terminal shell access and FTP are two different interfaces that do not have to return the same results.

Comment: I know the folder exist because the files I want are saved under `/foo/bar`. I guess I'm missing something... Anyway i can download the file

Comment: So either provide if any proof of the folder existence. Or if you do not want to pursue this anymore, please delete the question.